# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get data from API. I need to pass value from the body.

```
  signIn(String username,String password) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var jsonResponse = null;
 var response = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2:5554/api/login/login",
        headers : {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "charset":"utf-8"
        },
     body:{
       "username": '$username' ,
       "password":  '$password'
     });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Postman?

Comment: no sorry, I edit the question .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The body value you are passing is a map.

To make it work you could either change your header's *Content-Type* to: `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

OR

encode the map as a string and pass that to the body:

```
body: json.encode({"username": '$username', "password": '$password'});
```

Don't forget to `import 'dart:convert';` for the latter option.